# No trailing slash on React not being handled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-app-engine, routes, react-router

I have an issue where URL /covid19/ works but /covid19 does not (no slash at end).

When you check the network requests, it seems as the requests are being made to / instead of /covid19/

**/covid19 (no slash)**

[image]

**/covid19/ (with slash)**

[image]

I'm unsure if this is related to React's Router, this is my config:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path={"/covid19"} component={dashboard}/>
      <Route path={"/"} component={dashboard}/>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The site is:
https://datcom-website.uc.r.appspot.com/covid19/

My server is running on an App Engine instance.

Comment: put `<Route exact path={"/"} component={dashboard}/>` above the other and add an `exact`

Comment: it still doesn't work, it routes requests to / instead of /covid19/ @SakoBu

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you include the scripts in your HTML, not anything JS or React related.

Your script source is relative - `./path-to-script`; this makes it dependent on the URL. So from page `domain.com/exampleA` the path to script is `domain.com/path-to-script`, but as soon as you add another level in the URL, or even just a slash, the relative path changes. For example, `domain.com/exampleA/` produces the path `domain.com/exampleA/path-to-script`.

You should instead use an absolute path. Simply removing the `.` at the beginning is enough for most cases. Starting the source path with a `/` implies that its at the root level of the domain. So a source at `/path-to-source` will always yield `domain.com/path-to-script` no matter what the URL is.

So for your use case, it appears your scripts need to be changed to

```
<script src="/covid19/static/js/2.8cd0c9f0.chunk.js"></script>
<script src="/covid19/static/js/main.05f82414.chunk.js"></script>
```

Comment: When doing that the issue inverts. /covid19 works, /covid19/ doesn't.

 I get a request to '/covid19/covid19/static/js...' when accessing /covid19/ with a dash.

Comment: @EduardoMorales Its an absolute path, that's not how they work. Can you post a screenshot of your script tag in the HTML and the request being made? Are you Sure you removed the period at the beginning?